# Applying for French Visa

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, vfs-global

I travelled to France in Sept 2018 on a 3 month visa, where I travelled to the Chicago France VFS Center to get finger printed and bio-metrics done in Aug 2018. 
I have to travel to France again in July 2019. So do i have to make another personal appearance again or can I mail in my visa application. 
I live in Portland, US and on an Indian passport with Green Card.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to give biometrics again for a Schengen visa if less than [five years](https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/changes-in-schengen-visa-application-process-india_en.pdf) has passed since the last time you gave biometrics. The biometrics are stored in the [Visa Information System](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system_en) where they are available to all Schengen states for that period.